# Extending default copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor

In a copy constructor of a `struct/class`, how can I avoid copying all the basic (`int`, `double`, etc.) members one by one if the intention is to copy a pointer successfully? Is it possible to extend the default copy constructor in this sense?

```
struct Type
{
    int a;
    double b;
    bool c;
    // ... a lot of basic members
    int* p;

    Type()
    {
        p = new int;
        *p = 0;
    }

    Type (const Type& t)
    {
        // how to avoid copying these members one by one
        this.a = t.a;
        this.b = t.b;
        this.c = t.c;

        // but only add this portion
        this.p = new int;
        *this.p = *t.p;
    }
};
```

Comment: Use a smart pointer for `p` and get rid of the copy constructor altogether.

Comment: @DieterLücking, you are right. He shouldn't use the default assignment operator.

Comment: @chris A smart pointer is only responsible to free resources, not to acquire them. A copy constructor needs to acquire resources.

Comment: @dyp, Given another smart pointer, it would acquire the resource from that. `shared_ptr` has a copy constructor for that and `unique_ptr` has a move constructor for that. The point where that fails is if you want a `unique_ptr` in a copyable class, in which case you have to clone the object yourself.

Comment: Could you be more big-picture about what your are trying to achieve?  In the example you posted, there is no reason to be using pointers at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an RAII wrapper for the `int *` data member that allows copying/moving.

```
struct DynInt
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> p;

    DynInt() : DynInt(0) {}
    explicit DynInt(int i) : p(new int(i)) {}
    DynInt(DynInt const &other) : p(new int(*other.p)) {}
    DynInt& operator=(DynInt const& other)
    {
        *p = *other.p;
        return *this;
    }
    DynInt(DynInt&&) = default;
    DynInt& operator=(DynInt&&) = default;

    // maybe define operator* to allow direct access to *p
};
```

Then declare your class as

```
struct Type
{
    int a;
    double b;
    bool c;
    // ... a lot of basic members
    DynInt p;
};
```

Now, the implicitly generated copy constructor will do the right thing.

Comment: If the `DynInt(int)` ctor is implicit, maybe add an `operator int()` for "symmetry".

Comment: @dyp I think I prefer the explicit constructor. Thanks for noticing that.